# Which function is better SUBSTR or RPAD as oracle query performance

Tags: sql, oracle

Making a oracle query and need to chose a function  `SUBSTR` or `RPAD`. but I am not sure about the function performance which one is better.

Here are two conditions:

**Condition 1:**

```
where SUBSTR('Jasonx',0,4) = SUBSTR('Jasonxxxxx',0,4);
```

**Condition 2:**

```
where RPAD('Jasonx',10,x)='Jasonxxxxx'
```

Comment: Measure them both with *your* data and *your* queries and find out?

Comment: Both seem to produce different results (`SUBSTR('JASO123', 0, 4) = SUBSTR('JASO567', 0, 4)` is true, with padding it is false) so comparing performance does not make sense.

Comment: As soon as you're running a query against a table (presumably using data from the table, rather than literal values), and you're calling at least one string function, the performance difference between different string functions will be negligible. Choose the one that leads to clearer code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably neither is better. None of those *conditions* uses any column names so this is *fabricated*. If it was, for example,

```
where substr(username, 1, 4) = substr('JASON', 1, 4)
or
where rpad(username, 15, 'x') = 'JASONxxxxxxxxxx'
```

then both of them wouldn't be able to use a possible index on the `USERNAME` column - you should create a *function-based index* in that case.

Which one of them will run faster? Who knows; you should measure it. The first step is to check explain plan, such as

```
SQL> select * from emp where ename = 'KING';

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81      10000                    10


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |    39 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     1 |    39 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("ENAME"='KING')

SQL>
```